# Tensorboard projector will compute PCA endlessly

Tags: tensorflow, pca, gensim, tensorboard

I have just over 100k word embeddings which I created using gensim, originally each containing 200 dimensions. I've been trying to visualize them within tensorboard's projector but I have only failed so far.
My problem is that tensorboard seems to freeze while computing PCA. At first, I left the page open for 16 hours, imagining that it was just too much to be calculated, but nothing happened. At this point, I started to try and test different scenarios just in case all I needed was more time and I was trying to rush things. The following is a list of my testing so far, all of which failed at the same spot, computing PCA:

- I plotted only 10 points of 200 dimensions;
- I retrained my gensim model so that I could reduce its dimensionality to 100;
- Then I reduced it to 10;
- Then to 2;
- Then I tried plotting only 2 points, i.e. 2 two dimensional points;

I am using Tensorflow 1.11;
You can find my last saved tensor flow session [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10Cnzc2RH9nDFUYrf51r6d8d0jsl0-H6Y), would you mind trying it out?

I am still a beginner, therefore I used a couple tutorial to get me started; I used [Sud Harsan](https://github.com/sudharsan13296/visualise-word2vec/blob/master/Word2vec%20Embeddings.ipynb) work so far.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

---

Updates:

A) I've found someone else [dealing with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054907/tensorfboard-embeddings-hangs-with-computing-pca); I tried the solution provided, but it didn't change anything.

B) I thought it could have something to do with my installation, therefore I tried uninstalling tensorflow and installing it back; no luck. I then proceeded to create a new environment dedicated to tensorflow and that also didn't work.

C) Assuming there was something wrong with my code, I ran [tensorflow's basic embedding tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py) to check if I could open its projector's results. And guess what?! I still can't go past "Calculating PCA"

Now, I did visit [the online projector example](https://projector.tensorflow.org) and that loads perfectly.

Again, Any help would be more than appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Bluedrops, updating tensorboard and tensorflow seems to fix the problem.

I created a new environment with conda and installed the newest versions of Tensorflow, Tensorboard and their dependencies and that seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem with [word2vec_basic.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/word2vec/word2vec_basic.py)

My environment: win10, conda, python 3.6.7, tensorflow 1.11, tensorboard 1.11

That may not your fault because I roll back tensorflow & tensorboard from 1.11 to 1.7

And guess what?! The projector appears just a few seconds!

[reference](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1480)

---

Update 10/11

tensorboard & tensorflow 1.12 are available in conda today, I take a try and this problem seems to be fixed.

Comment: Can you mention exactly which version? I updated to 
`tensorboard 1.12.2` and `tensorflow 1.12.0` on Conda and I still have this issue.

Comment: @jwsmithers My environment now is tf1.12.0 and tb1.12.2 on conda, I run that code just now and everything is OK.